# Where does this definition for the free variables of a formula come from?

Tags: logic

I am doing some reading about this and I have come across the definition of a free variable.

The free variables of a formula, $F V (\varphi)$, are defined by induction on the structure of $\varphi$:
$$FV(\varphi \lor \psi) = FV(\varphi \land \psi) = FV(\varphi \supset \psi) = FV(\varphi) \cup FV(\psi)$$
I do not understand where this come from.

Comment: Similar topics were considered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/679744/26306), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/474893/26306) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/801448/26306).

Comment: It "comes from" from the inductive def of $\varphi$ ... If $\varphi$ is an *atomic* formula, it is like $x=0$ or $0 < 1$, with only *terms* (i.e. variables and constants) and predicate letters, i.e. **no** connectives and quantifiers. Thus, if some term in it has a variable "inside" it must be necessarily a *free* one. In $x=0$ there is an occurrence of the var $x$ and thus it is necessarily free. In $0 < 1$ there are no occurrences of vars, and thus no free vars in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally it doesn't "come from" anywhere -- it is a *definition*.

Intuitively, the free variables in a formula are all the variables that appear in it, *except* that it doesn't count when variable appears within the scope of a quantifier that binds.

The symbolic definition simply makes precise what that intuition means. The case you quote is a shorthand for the three separate cases
$$ \begin{align}
\operatorname{FV}(\varphi\lor\psi) &=\operatorname{FV}(\varphi)\cup\operatorname{FV}(\psi) \\
\operatorname{FV}(\varphi\land\psi) &=\operatorname{FV}(\varphi)\cup\operatorname{FV}(\psi) \\
\operatorname{FV}(\varphi\supset\psi) &=\operatorname{FV}(\varphi)\cup\operatorname{FV}(\psi)
\end{align} $$
You ought to have additional cases for the other forms of wff, as well as for terms.

Comment: Yeah I have a whole load of them for other forms. So it is just a case of learning them all.

Comment: @user99865: Instead of learning all of the rules by rote you should understand the intuition of what they _do_; you can then easily write down each particular rule when you need it. All the rules that are _not_ about quantifiers simply say "ignore the connectives and take everything that is free in a subformula". The quantifier rules say "take everything that is free in the formula _under_ the quantifier, except the variable the quantifier binds". Everything beyond this is just mindless fleshing-out of this principle to the particular syntax your logic has.

Comment: ok, do you mind giving me an intuitive example of the example I put up please?

Comment: @user99865: I'm sorry, I don't understand which example you're speaking of.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was referring to the example on the original post. Where it says...defined by induction on the structure of...

Comment: @user99865: Are you looking for something like $\operatorname{FV}(x\ne y\land \forall z[z>w\to x\ne z])$ is $\{x,y,w\}$ because $\operatorname{FV}(x\ne y)=\{x,y\}$ and $\operatorname{FV}(\forall z[z>w\to x\ne z])=\{x,w\}$?

Comment: I am not sure, that seems quite difficult. Another example the teacher gave us is            FV(t1=t2) = FV(t1) u FV(t2)   How would you explain the intuition of this? (if I know how to do it for one I can do it for the others) thanks mate

Comment: @user99865: Ignoring quantifiers (which cannot appear in terms) the free variables in a formula are simply all the variables that appear _anywhere_ in the formula. So if the formula looks like $t_1=t_2$, and $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms, then the variables that appear anywhere are those that appear in $t_1$ together with those that appear in $t_2$. So, for example for the concrete formula $f(x,y)=g(x,z)$, the free variables are $\{x,y,z\}$ -- just all the variables.

Comment: thank you mate. Great answer.Do you have any advice for studying logic?